# Can't run right path for husky_custom_description

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am launching the rviz for Husky clearpath however, there are issues with the `husky_custom_description` directory. Here is the errors that I get from launching `roslaunch husky_viz view_robot.launch`:

```
[ERROR] [1509570289.212759654]: Could not load resource [package://husky_custom_description/meshes/red_bowler.dae]: Unable to open file "package://husky_custom_description/meshes/red_bowler.dae".
[ WARN] [1509570289.212988793]: OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://husky_custom_description/meshes/red_bowler.dae in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
[ERROR] [1509570289.213233837]: Could not load model 'package://husky_custom_description/meshes/red_bowler.dae' for link 'bowler_link': OGRE EXCEPTION(6:FileNotFoundException): Cannot locate resource package://husky_custom_description/meshes/red_bowler.dae in resource group Autodetect or any other group. in ResourceGroupManager::openResource at /build/buildd/ogre-1.8-1.8.1+dfsg/OgreMain/src/OgreResourceGroupManager.cpp (line 756)
```

From what I noticed, it seems they look at the wrong path because in my `husky_custom_description/meshes` doesn't contain `red_bowler.dae` but another file name `wisu01_husky_arch.dae`. I tried to redirect the path using `EXPORT ROS_PACKAGE_PATH="my file directory"`, but it still appears the same errors. I run the command `env |grep` ROS to check here is what I have:

```
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/baxter/catkin_ws/src:/home/baxter/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://cpr-A200-0367:11311
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=/home/baxter/catkin_ws/devel/share/common-lisp:/home/baxter/catkin_ws/devel/share/common-lisp
ROS_DISTRO=indigo
ROS_IP=192.168.0.103
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/indigo/etc/ros
```

my catkin workspace name `catkin_ws`, so i guess the paths are correct in this. So I am not sure what to do to make the roslaunch rviz looks at the right path to launch the right `husky_custom_description/meshes/wisu01_husky_arch.dae` instead of `/husky_custom_description/meshes/red_bowler.dae`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274767/can%27t-run-right-path-for-husky_custom_description/) by [kimnguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/31650/kimnguyen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-11-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That CAD file is probably added in the URDF. Have you looked at husky_custom_description/urdf/husky.urdf.xacro and the other urdf's there?

Try:

```
roscd husky_custom_description
grep -r 'red_bowler.dae'
```

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2017-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0